# Amazon RDS instances get deleted automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created an Amazon RDS cluster with two instances i.e read and write, after 5-10 minutes those instances gets deleted automatically. I had created a DB subnet group containing public subnet Ids, is this the issue?
Do AWS does not allow to create databases in public subnet within VPC?

Comment: Are there any cloudwatch logs / cloudwatch events as to why this might be happening ?

Comment: Follow this, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateDBInstance.html

Comment: Amazon RDS databases do not get deleted. Something must be requesting it to be deleted. Take a look at **AWS CloudTrail** and try to find the API call that is deleting the database.